# Yii CGridView catch Ajax Response and solve session timeout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, yii

I am using `Yii MVC`;

The user is logged in;

I am using a browser with 2 tabs;

From the 2nd tab, I log out the user, so, now, the user is logged oput also from the 1st tab;

Now, I am trying to query the `db` using a `ajax call` within a `gridview`;

The user is logged out, so, I get a `302` status code;

This is where I want to catch this error, and redirect the user to the login page, because the session has expired;

Internally, Yii tryes to redirect me to the `login` page, but fails;

I see the `login` action with `200` status code, but no redirect;

I found some info about this behavior, but it does not work:

[Using loginRequiredAjaxResponse to solve ajax session timeout](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/321/using-loginrequiredajaxresponse-to-solve-ajax-session-timeout/)

I tryed to use a fresh yii project, because i suspected that the `user module` is to blame;

It is not the user module, its yii;

In the framework, in the `CAccessControlFilter`, the following function is called;

If the session has expired and i refresh the page, i can see the die message;

But if the session has expired and I have a ajax call, the redirect does not happen;

```
protected function accessDenied($user,$message)
    {
        die(__FUNCTION__);
        debug_print_backtrace();
        if($user->getIsGuest())
            $user->loginRequired();
        else
            throw new CHttpException(403,$message);
    }
```

in the `main.php` file, under components -> user,  i set `'loginRequiredAjaxResponse' => 'YII_LOGIN_REQUIRED',`

Comment: Share some code please.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/321/using-loginrequiredajaxresponse-to-solve-ajax-session-timeout/`

in template or view put this code:

```
<?php
        /*
         * if ajax call and session has expired, then redirect to user/login
         */
        if (Yii::app()->components['user']->loginRequiredAjaxResponse) {
            Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('ajaxLoginRequired', '
            jQuery("body").ajaxComplete(
                function(event, request, options) {
                    if (request.responseText == "' . Yii::app()->components['user']->loginRequiredAjaxResponse . '") {
                        window.location.href = "'.Yii::app()->createUrl('/user/login').'";
                    }
                }
            );
        ');
        }
        ?>
```

in the custom member controller, put this, in the init method

```
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        /*
         *  covers even the ajax requests if user session has expired
         */
        Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
    }
```